# Ejaculating while sleeping

Tags: penis, waking-up, ejaculation, pre-ejaculate-cum, semen

I've been ejaculating huge amounts of semen overnight, and I have to wake up and change my clothes and clean up before I can go back to sleep.

Is there something I can do to prevent ejaculation during my sleeping hours?

Comment: Requests for personal medical advice are off topic here.

Answer (score 5):

Nocturnal emissions [(q.v.)](https://sexinfoonline.com/nocturnal-orgasms-and-emissions/) are completely normal and generally nothing to worry about.